# Lock packages version with Yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

we are about to set up a production build server to maintain a embedded linux product. I know that I can specify a package version with `PREFERRED_VERSION_<package>` inside the recipe, but this may take *a lot* of time to lock every single tool in the image (i.e. `grep`, `strace`, ecc). This will be useful in case we need to rebuild the server (we could backup the whole server, but this wont be traced. Even commit everything to a git repo seems to be not so clever, correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there a way to get something like `package-lock.json` or an image footprint?

**EDIT**

What I'd like to achieve is a list of

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_<package0> = "xxx"
...
PREFERRED_VERSION_<packageN> = "xxx"
```

that I can use to replicate the image on a clear system (without any cached file). It seems that there is no such command to do that directly, instead it's possible to get a list of image packages and version by

```
bitbake <image> -s
```

and with a simple script generates what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have distro configuration, where you can specify all the version preferences. For example, the below samples are copied from [poky.conf](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-poky/conf/distro/poky-bleeding.conf) and [bleeding.conf](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta-poky/conf/distro/include/poky-floating-revisions.inc)

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_glib-2.0 ?= "2.17.4"
PREFERRED_VERSION_glib-2.0-native ?= "2.17.4"
PREFERRED_VERSION_atk ?= "1.22.0"
PREFERRED_VERSION_pango ?= "1.21.2"
PREFERRED_VERSION_gtk+ ?= "2.13.3"

require conf/distro/include/poky-floating-revisions.inc
require conf/distro/poky.conf

DISTRO = "poky-bleeding"
DISTROOVERRIDES = "poky"
```

So you can define all the `SRCREV` and `PREFERRED_VERSION` in distro configuration or write a separate `distro.inc` and add it using `require`. And to use this for compilation, you can define,

```
DISTRO ?= "poky-bleeding"
```

in your `conf/local.conf`. This way you can control all the version and SRCREV for git based recipes at place.

Comment: Alright, but what if I build an image with latest revision and I want a snapshot of that revision, so the image can be duplicated even if I start from scratch (with the needed meta layer already imported)? If I get it, in your solution I have to gather all the version by hand (or script) and then write a `distro.inc` with them. am I right?

Comment: @gabbla: Yes you need to maintain the versions someway or other. If I understand correctly, you question is about to maintain the needed version all at one place.

Comment: @gabbla: If you build with latest revision, then yocto stores all the information as cache and when you re-build the same version again into new scratch build, yocto can use the sstate cache to copy the binary instead of building it from source. For that you need specify common `SSTATE_DIR` in your `conf/local.conf`

Comment: yes, that was the point, I will maintain a `distro.inc` that is easier to keep under version control and provide it to any distro that need it. About `SSTATE_DIR`, I won't depend on sources pre-downloaded, because there might be the case where I don't have that cache and checking out the latest version may result in a newer package, then in a different image

Comment: @gabbla: So what's you question here? If you switch to latest version, you will be downloaded with new source version and compilation will be done from source. That's way it should work. When you want to re-do the same version, it can copy from cache. But yocto relies on version, when you change it, it will add that to task queue and re-compile it.

Comment: Maybe I said that badly, I'd like to know if there is a way to reproduce an image starting from Yocto given by our supplier and our meta layer, without any other cached file. While I can fix the version for the package added by us, I'd like to know if it's possible to get a file (like `distro.inc`) with every package version inside the final image in a standard manner

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183625/discussion-between-parthiban-and-gabbla).